# 'TensorDataset' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: pytorch, dataset, tensor

I tried to load csv file into tensor dataset for vertical federated learning.
The reference website is https://github.com/OpenMined/PyVertical/blob/master/examples/PyVertical%20Example.ipynb

Below is how I loaded the file but failed

```
train = pd.read_csv('datatrain.csv')   # load data

cols = ["a","b,"c"]   # select feature columns

train_feature = train[cols]   # create dataset with features
train_target = train['result']   # the dataset with result

# turn them in to torch.tensor data
train_feature_tensor = torch.tensor(train_feature.values)
train_target_tensor = torch.tensor(train_target.values)

# Put them into a TensorDataset
train_tensor = data_utils.dataset.TensorDataset(train_feature_tensor, train_target_tensor)

# them put them in to add_ids()
temp = add_ids(data_utils.dataset.TensorDataset)
temp.data = train_tensor
traindata_ft = temp(train_tensor)
```

Output:

```
'TensorDataset' object has no attribute 'size'
```

They pointed out the problem is from:

```
assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors)
```

which is in:

```
class TensorDataset(Dataset):
    r"""Dataset wrapping tensors.

    Each sample will be retrieved by indexing tensors along the first dimension.

    Arguments:
        *tensors (Tensor): tensors that have the same size of the first dimension.
    """

    def __init__(self, *tensors):
        assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors)
        self.tensors = tensors

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return tuple(tensor[index] for tensor in self.tensors)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.tensors[0].size(0)
```

About add_ids(), it is a function that generates unique id to each data row.
The original code is below

```
def add_ids(cls):
    """Decorator to add unique IDs to a dataset
    Args:
        cls (torch.utils.data.Dataset) : dataset to generate IDs for
    Returns:
        VerticalDataset : A class which wraps cls to add unique IDs as an attribute,
            and returns data, target, id when __getitem__ is called
    """

    class VerticalDataset(cls):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            self.ids = np.array([uuid4() for _ in range(len(self))])

        def __getitem__(self, index):
            if self.data is None:
                img = None
            else:
                img = self.data[index]
                img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode="L")

                if self.transform is not None:
                    img = self.transform(img)

            if self.targets is None:
                target = None
            else:
                target = int(self.targets[index]) if self.targets is not None else None

                if self.target_transform is not None:
                    target = self.target_transform(target)

            id = self.ids[index]

            # Return a tuple of non-None elements
            return (*filter(lambda x: x is not None, (img, target, id)),)

        def __len__(self):
            if self.data is not None:
                return self.data.size(0)
            else:
                return len(self.targets)

        def get_ids(self) -> List[str]:
            """Return a list of the ids of this dataset."""
            return [str(id_) for id_ in self.ids]

        def sort_by_ids(self):
            """
            Sort the dataset by IDs in ascending order
            """
            ids = self.get_ids()
            sorted_idxs = np.argsort(ids)

            if self.data is not None:
                self.data = self.data[sorted_idxs]

            if self.targets is not None:
                self.targets = self.targets[sorted_idxs]

            self.ids = self.ids[sorted_idxs]

    return VerticalDataset
```

Comment: Hello, what is `add_ids` supposed to do and return ? This is not declared in your code snippet. Please try to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example :) Anyway, no dataset from pytorch will have a `size` method, only `__len__`. However `size` can be called for tensor, which seems to be what the assertion was expecting. You need to find why you are putting a dataset where a tensor was expected

Comment: @trialNerror Thank you for reminding. I just added the `add_ids` explanation on the post. ```add_ids``` generally create unique id to each data row. really appreciate your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it is clearer now ! So `add_idx` creates a new class which inherits from the one you give as arguments. Therefore when you call

```
temp = add_ids(data_utils.dataset.TensorDataset)
```

`temp` is actually a child class from `TensorDataset`. The way its `__init__` is implemented means that you can instantiate it by giving it the parameters you would give to instantiate a `TensorDataset`, NOT by giving it an instance of `TensorDataset`, which is exactly what you do here :

```
# Put them into a TensorDataset
train_tensor = data_utils.dataset.TensorDataset(train_feature_tensor, train_target_tensor)
# train_tensor is a dataset, NOT a tensor !
traindata_ft = temp(train_tensor)
```

So what you should do instead is :

```
# More explicit and useful name, instead of `temp`
VerticalTensorDataset = add_ids(data_utils.dataset.TensorDataset)
# Instantiate it with tensors
traindata_ft  = VerticalTensorDataset(train_feature_tensor, train_target_tensor)
```